# Pull column names along with data in Teradata Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, teradata

I am running the below snippet in python:

```
with udaExec.connect(method="ODBC", system=<server IP>,username=<user>,password=<pwd>) as session:

    for row in session.execute("""sel top 3 * from retail.employee"""):
        print(row)
```

The above query is returning data without the column names. How do I pull column names along with data from the `employee` table while using teradata python module in python3.x ?

Answer (score 1):

I will use pandas and teradata to get full control of data.

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd

with udaExec.connect(method="ODBC", system=<server IP>,username=<user>,password=<pwd>) as session:

    query = '''sel top 3 * from re

    tail.employee'''
    df = pd.read_sql(query,session)

print(df.columns.tolist()) #columns
print(df.head(2)) # beautiful first 2 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found pandas pretty pretty thick, but useful at times.

But I see the column names are in the cursor description: https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/#CursorAttributes

The index isn't working for me in pypi for this page, so you'll probably have to scroll down, but you should find the following:

```
.description

Read-only attribute consisting of a sequence of seven-item sequences that each describe a result set column, available after a SQL request is executed.

.description[Column][0] provides the column name.
.description[Column][1] provides the column type code as an object comparable to one of the Type Objects listed below.
.description[Column][2] provides the column display size in characters. Not implemented yet.
.description[Column][3] provides the column size in bytes.
.description[Column][4] provides the column precision if applicable, or None otherwise.
.description[Column][5] provides the column scale if applicable, or None otherwise.
.description[Column][6] provides the column nullability as True or False.
```

If you want to replicate pandas to_dict, you can do the following:

```
    with teradatasql.connect(**conn) as con:
        with con.cursor () as cur:
            cur.execute("sel top 3 * from retail.employee;")
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            columns=[d[0] for d in cur.description]
            list_of_dict=[{columns[i]:rows[j][i] for i in range(0,len(columns))} for j in range(1,len(rows[0]))]
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "Name":"John Doe",
        "SomeOtherEmployeeColumn":"arbitrary data"
    }

]
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
with udaExec.connect(method="ODBC", system=<server IP>,username=<user>,password=<pwd>) as session:

for row in session.execute("""sel top 3 * from retail.employee"""):
        print(row.name + ": " row.val)
```